# Find the average but without using range

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, average

Just want to ask if there is an easy way for me to find the average but not using range since the values are placed in different cells?

Here the cells and the formula that I'm using to get the average (J28+O28+T28+Y28+AD28+AI28+AN28+AS28+AX28)/9

It is working, yes. But the problem is that there is a cell that the value may be empty. For example, all of it has a value except for AS28 & AX28, so the denominator should be 6 and not 9.

Is there a way for me to easily do this? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of data is in the OTHER cells (i.e., the ones between those you want to include in the average)? Are they all text for instance? Or if everything is numerical, is there anything that sets the numbers in question apart from the others (e.g., all negative? all over a certain amount? all...?). It's always best to show, as opposed to simply tell, what you're working with. Details matter and may reveal much simpler solutions.

Comment: @ErikTyler I'm sorry and noted with that. I will be more detailed next time. Thank you for the response.

Comment: I was actually asking for answers, toward trying to perhaps see if there might be an easier solution for you. So if you still want to share the details I asked about, I'll look at them. If you're happy with the solutions already offered, however, great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
=AVERAGE(J28,O28,T28,Y28,AD28,AI28,AN28,AS28,AX28)
```

It will happily ignore empty and non-numeric cells

<sub>Note: your cells list included 9 cells, so that sould be `/9` right?</sub>

Comment: This works fine! Thank you! And yes, it is 9 so thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNTA()` function to exclude empty cells. Try below formula-

```
=(J28+O28+T28+Y28+AD28+AI28+AN28+AS28+AX28)/COUNTA(J28,O28,T28,Y28,AD28,AI28,AN28,AS28,AX28)
```

Comment: I tried this. I put two 90 in the those cells, but the average turns to be 20.